# How do I build and deploy a Bun app via Netlify?

Tags: netlify, bun

So I've made a Bun app using `bun create react`

Now I'm looking to deploy it to production (via Netlify) and am at a loss as to how.

`bun build` doesn't seem to work. Is there a specific command that's not in the documentation?

Answer (score 5):

### Updated answer for Bun 1.0

> `bun create` and `bun dev` were deprecated in Bun 1.0, so the updated answer is going to ignore that part of the question

If you plan to use Bun with your React application the recommended way is to use it with Vite/Next/etc, mostly as a drop-in replacement for `npm` or `node`.

I created [a template project](https://github.com/JLarky/bun-netlify) that uses Vite (React, no SSG/SSR) and uses Bun in development and production (Netlify).

Keep in mind that most of the benefits from using this approach is actually going to be savings from running `bun install` because running `vite build` with Bun is slightly slower at the moment. But `bun install` could be 2-10 times faster.

##### Original answer from Dec 2022

There are no production builds of Bun yet (as of version 0.3 at least). So you would need to use something like react-scripts or Vite.

I have built an example project just for this question :) https://github.com/JLarky/bun-netlify/tree/react-scripts (this only works in Bun 0.x)

The main steps are:

1. add `react-scripts`
2. disable `npm install` on CI
3. install bun binary on CI
4. use that binary to install dependencies and build the project
5. ...
6. PROFIT (builds on CI started to run 2-3 times faster)